# How to sort a DataGridView based on its column content?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datagridview, bindinglist

Here GrdView is a DataGridView.
And 'obj.Code' is of Alphanumeric type (like R12, BA3, BA21...)

```
private SortableBindingList<myClass> objList = new SortableBindingList<myClass>();

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("code", typeof(string));

foreach (var obj in objList)
{
    table.Rows.Add(obj.Code);
}

GrdView.DataSource = table;
```

This Sorts the DataGridView by clicking its column header, but sorting is alphanumeric.
I want to sort the DataGridView's column by only its numeric content (not leading alphabet.)

Comment: You should accept an answer when you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another column by which to sort (you can make it's Visible property = false).  Paste all of this code into a new windows Form and it will work exactly as you described (delete the FormX.designer.cs file).  The SortableCode column uses Regular Expressions to remove the leading alpha characters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowQuestion21361045
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class myClass
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }

            public string SortableCode
            {
                get
                {
                    return Regex.Replace(Code, @"^[^\d]+", string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        private readonly SortableBindingList<myClass> objList = new SortableBindingList<myClass>();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objList.Add(new myClass {Code = "A23"});
            objList.Add(new myClass {Code = "B12"});
            objList.Add(new myClass {Code = "C04" });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = objList;
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn newColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
            DataGridViewColumn previouslySortedColumn = dataGridView1.SortedColumn;
            ListSortDirection direction;

            if (newColumn == dataGridView1.Columns[0])
                newColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[1]; //if the user sorts by code, change the column so as to sort by SortableCode
            // If oldColumn is null, then the DataGridView is not sorted. 
            if (previouslySortedColumn != null)
            {
                // Sort the same column again, reversing the SortOrder. 
                if (previouslySortedColumn == newColumn &&
                    dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Sort a new column and remove the old SortGlyph.
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                    previouslySortedColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }

            // Sort the selected column.
            dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction);
            newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
                direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
                SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
            DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            // Put each of the columns into programmatic sort mode. 
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);
            this.dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;

        public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
        {
            private ArrayList sortedList;
            private ArrayList unsortedItems;
            private bool isSortedValue;

            public SortableBindingList()
            {
            }

            public SortableBindingList(IList<T> list)
            {
                foreach (object o in list)
                {
                    this.Add((T)o);
                }
            }

            protected override bool SupportsSearchingCore
            {
                get
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            protected override int FindCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, object key)
            {
                PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name);
                T item;

                if (key != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
                    {
                        item = (T)Items[i];
                        if (propInfo.GetValue(item, null).Equals(key))
                            return i;
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }

            public int Find(string property, object key)
            {
                PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
                    TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
                PropertyDescriptor prop = properties.Find(property, true);

                if (prop == null)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return FindCore(prop, key);
            }

            protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
            {
                get { return true; }
            }


            protected override bool IsSortedCore
            {
                get { return isSortedValue; }
            }

            ListSortDirection sortDirectionValue;
            PropertyDescriptor sortPropertyValue;

            protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop,
                ListSortDirection direction)
            {
                sortedList = new ArrayList();

                Type interfaceType = prop.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable");

                if (interfaceType == null && prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                {
                    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);

                    if (underlyingType != null)
                    {
                        interfaceType = underlyingType.GetInterface("IComparable");
                    }
                }

                if (interfaceType != null)
                {
                    sortPropertyValue = prop;
                    sortDirectionValue = direction;

                    IEnumerable<T> query = base.Items;
                    if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        query = query.OrderBy(i => prop.GetValue(i));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(i => prop.GetValue(i));
                    }
                    int newIndex = 0;
                    foreach (object item in query)
                    {
                        this.Items[newIndex] = (T)item;
                        newIndex++;
                    }
                    isSortedValue = true;
                    this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot sort by " + prop.Name +
                        ". This" + prop.PropertyType.ToString() +
                        " does not implement IComparable");
                }
            }

            protected override void RemoveSortCore()
            {
                int position;
                object temp;

                if (unsortedItems != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < unsortedItems.Count; )
                    {
                        position = this.Find("LastName",
                            unsortedItems[i].GetType().
                            GetProperty("LastName").GetValue(unsortedItems[i], null));
                        if (position > 0 && position != i)
                        {
                            temp = this[i];
                            this[i] = this[position];
                            this[position] = (T)temp;
                            i++;
                        }
                        else if (position == i)
                            i++;
                        else
                            unsortedItems.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    isSortedValue = false;
                    OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
                }
            }

            public void RemoveSort()
            {
                RemoveSortCore();
            }
            protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
            {
                get { return sortPropertyValue; }
            }

            protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
            {
                get { return sortDirectionValue; }
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, John C. I solved the problem by modifying my SortableBindingList class with your code example help.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way around this problem is to add another column that only contains the numbers.
You can't really sort an array based on a sub-part of the cells.

The sorting will have to do an awful lot of comparisons (at least n*ln(n)) and thus transforming the strings for each access is not a good practice.

What you should do is transform only once the column into its equivalent numeric form and then sort by that column.

After the sort you may drop the column and then pass it all to be rendered in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Two options -

1. You can catch the SortCompare event and modify its behavior to fit your needs. Take a look at the second example here - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
2. You can catch the [ColumnHeaderMouseClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then run [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) manually with the IComparer that fits your needs

Like pid says in his answer, given a large number of elements, performance is something to take into account when implementing the logic that compares. But I would first test it on a big set of data to make sure there is a problem before implementing a complex solution.